# Type script Object should allow a particular property at a time

Tags: typescript

I am new to typescript i have an object `obj` and It has 3 properties. a, b, c. among these **b and c will not come together** in an object. ie My object will be either

```
obj = {
    a: 'xxx',
    b: 'xxx'
}
```

or

```
obj = {
    a: 'xxx',
    c: 'xxx'
}
```

. How can i define the type of `obj`.

Answer (score 1):

That's not what typescript is for, you can only define a structure of your objects but not a relation like you would like to have.

You can do it two ways. Either you define two types and say your final object is either type A or type B:

```
const myObj: typeA | typeB;
```

And in typeA you define properties a + c, in typeB you define a + b.

Or you can do it so:

You define

```
obj = {
  'a': string,
  'b'?: string,
  'c'?: string
}
```

You set both parameters to optional. And you do all logic checks in your component / `.ts` file.